# Использование кавычек при употреблении словосочетания "круглый стол"

Tags: орфография

Нужно ли брать в кавычки словосочетание "круглый стол", имея в виду совещание и т. д.?

Answer (score 4):

Не обязательно. Образное или переносное значение слова нужно заключать в кавычки.

Однако это вполне устоявшееся словосочетание.

Подробнее см. например тут: http://www.gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/rr/28_123